# nextjs 13 routing change causes all client component re-render and lost state?

Tags: next.js13

use nextjs13 app router. where use router.push() or Link change route, always causes all page request, then causes all component re-render, it so painful. all client component state (use useState) reseted at re-render.

this demo is nextjs12 page dir: https://8z3msx-3000.csb.app/items/item1
this demo is nextjs13 app dir: https://sd9c2v-3000.csb.app/items/item2

can see in nextjs13 the state is clear when click Link, but nextjs12 only first time request is service side render, then click Link, it use client side render, and the state is keepped.

then I found the office domo this link https://app-router.vercel.app/context .them use a context wrapper the client component like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VYXe.png)

ok I can use this way to avoid state being reset. Although this method is quite cumbersome

but I got a new problem. I have so many tabs in my page like this, some tab is overflow and hided :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3WGS.png)

when I click the tab, I want let the clicked tab scroll to the center of page use js add transform style. in nextjs12 is ok. but in nextjs13 it so painful. because click tab I call router.push method change url, in nextjs13 it make component re-render, so every time it make tab goto the first init state ....

I don't know how to deal with this kind of problem, every time component re-render where route change.

I don't know if there's something wrong with the way I'm using nextjs13. or if nextjs13 is designed this way?

Who can help me answer this question or provide some ideas?

I want to know if nextjs13 route changes can be done without re-rendering the all page.